# Automatically deploy .rdl files to PowerBI

Tags: powershell, powerbi, ssrs-2012, powerbi-embedded, rdl

My team maintains a few dozen legacy reports, expressed as .rdl files, currently hosted in an SSRS server. This as part of a .Net Core 8 web site. Additionally, we want to start using the cloud hosted Embedded PowerBI service to show graphs to our end users.

I understand that .rdl files can be imported into PowerBI. So I'm thinking of ditching the SSRS server and use PowerBI to host the .rdl files. This means that when we do a release, we would deploy the .rdl files to the PowerBI service as part of the automated release process.

Is there some way to import .rdl files automatically into the Embedded PowerBI service? For example, could it be done with Powershell?